# Обстоятельство - проблемы с пониманием

Tags: синтаксис

Здравствуйте, помогите разобраться, пожалуйста. 
"По рассеянности перепутал уроки". Это обстоятельство цели или причины?
 И еще одно предложение.
"Тогда игры проводились в течение летних месяцев в городе Олимпия". Если  "в городе" - обстоятельство места, то "Олимпия" будет приложением или будет входить в обстоятельство места? А слово " летних" будет входить в обстоятельство времени,  или  только "в течение месяцев", а "летних" будет определением?
Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 2):

"По рассеянности перепутал уроки". -перепутал по какой причине? -по рассеянности-обст. причины.

"Тогда игры проводились в течение летних месяцев в городе( каком?) Олимпия"-приложение.

Проводились когда? В течение летних месяцев - обст. времени.Это контекстуально цельное словосочетание, т.к.главное слово (в течение месяцев ) является недостаточным(летние месяцы=летом)

Контекстуально-цельные словосочетания - такие,цельность которыхх возникает только в контексте предложения или сложного словосочетания: умный человек сумеет разобраться в этом; девушка с голубыми глазами, человек высокого роста.

Answer (score 0):

Вот мнение  сайта Грамотно.ру..... [image: введите сюда описание изображения]